# How to change ckeditor ui color to solid

Tags: ckeditor

I am using Ckeditor 4. Setting the property uiColor makes it always gradient. Is there a way to setup a solid ui color?

Comment: Check uncompress file, here https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/skins/moono/skin.js, verticalGradient()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the inline editor with the 'sharedspace' plugin:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (e) {
  $('.cke_top').css('background','#eee');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found that doing things like this in CKEditor are extremely frustrating. I tried finding a way to do this for a long time and changed the skin.js file, and several other things. In the end, I fixed it by changing the property with jquery after the editor loaded.

```
$('.cke_inner').css('background','transparent');
```

You can substitute '#012345' for 'transparent' and it will be a solid color.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit `skin.js` in `/ckeditor_path/skins/skin_name/skin.js` and modify `CKEDITOR.skin.chameleon` part that controls uiColor management to get rid of gradients. No other clean & easy way.

Comment: Thanks. The only place where I can find that is in the ckeditor.js. I tried several ways to make it solid including remvoing the background-image:-moz-linear-gradient with no luck. Do you exactly what to modify?

Comment: Look for function `verticalGradient` in `moono/skin.js` (uncompressed code).

Comment: There is no file named skin.js. I tried to find verticalGradient in the whole package and there is not

Comment: Since you're using a compressed CKEditor, some variables and functions can have compressed names. [This part](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/skins/moono/skin.js#L109-L122) is responsible for creating gradients. Consider cloning the official [github repo](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-presets), setting ckeditor submodule to tag `git co 4.0.1.1`, editing source and calling `build.sh full all` to obtain the package.